# How to Detect Back Swipe in WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, wkwebview

Is it possible to detect a back swipe in a web view when there has not been any forward navigation?  The following code works fine if the user has moved off the first page but I want to know if they back swiped while on that page.

Update - This is the code I'm using after modifying it per comments.  I added the navigation back function and the swipe gesture.

```
    class WebViewClient: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    var webView: WKWebView!


    public func load(pageLink page: String)
    {
        print("Opening: " + page)

        if webView != nil
        {
            if let myURL = URL(string:page)
            {
                webUrlRequest = page

                let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)

                webView.load(myRequest)
             }
      }

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        print("Opened: " + webUrlRequest)
    }

    override func loadView()
    {
        let pref = WKPreferences()
        pref.javaScriptEnabled = true

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.preferences = pref


        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)

        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true


        view = webView
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
    {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .backForward && webView.backForwardList.backList.count == 0
        {
           print("Can't go back any more")
        }

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

    @objc func backNavigationFunction(_ sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let dX = sender.translation(in: view).x
        if sender.state == .ended
        {
            let fraction = abs(dX / view.bounds.width)
            if fraction >= 0.35
            {
                print("Back swipe")
                //back navigation code here
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let swipeGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backNavigationFunction(_:)))
        swipeGesture.edges = .left
        swipeGesture.delegate = self

        webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented any type of GestureRecognizer?

Comment: No.  Just the navigation function above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would implement a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to handle this.  Add the following to your `viewDidLoad`

```
let swipeGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backNavigationFunction(_:)))
    swipeGesture.edges = .left
    swipeGesture.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
```

Then, implement a function to handle the `backNavigationFunction` like below:

```
@objc func backNavigationFunction(_ sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    let dX = sender.translation(in: view).x
    if sender.state == .ended {
        let fraction = abs(dX / view.bounds.width)
        if fraction >= 0.35 {
            //back navigation code here
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make the ViewController inherit from the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` class (i.e. `class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`).  The delegate in question here is `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` but I anticipate you'll need the others as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So its implemented but the backNavigationFunction is never triggered.  Any ideas what I can check?

Comment: I added it to the main question.

Comment: Couple thoughts for you. If you’re doing this in a simulator, they can be finicky for detecting the gesture. I would try on a device if you haven’t yet.  The edge gesture has to be pretty much on the edge of the screen.  Have you set a break point in the backNavigationFunction? I’m interested to see if it’s firing.  The fraction is looking for 35% or more of the screen to have been swiped across.  How much of a swipe are you doing?

Comment: I’m running it on a recent iPad and have the break point set in the nav function before any calculations.

Comment: @zappullae, I just copied and pasted this, then ran this in a simulator and the code is executing.  I placed the breakpoint on the code "let dX = sender.translation(in: view).x"
Can you confirm the location of your breakpoint? Also, what iOS build are you targeting?

Comment: Same break point location and iOS 10 is the target.  I also tried putting the code in the MainActivty instead of the WebViewClient class with the same results.  I'll take another look at what is happening just to make sure I didn't fat finger anything.

Comment: I changed my build target to iOS 10 and it's still firing appropriately.  I uploaded a copy of my controller to this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EnMRWxMLngxhXVdj_RZF2U3SO_BRaB9T . Take a look and let me know if that helps.

Comment: So I have it working.  It turns out that my WebViewClient viewDidLoad() was not being invoked and the back swipe configuration not implemented.  I moved the code to my own loadView() function and now it works perfectly!  I am loading the WebVlientView with  present(webView, animated: true, completion: nil) from MainActivty.  Perhaps this doesn't cause viewDidLoad on the web client to be called.  Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: This is also cancelling the swipe transition itself. Is there a way to just detect and let the original transition proceed?